# How to prove #edges in a graph with combinatorial proof?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, proof-writing, combinations

Let k ≥ 1 be an integer and consider a sequence $n_1, n_2, . . . , n_k$ of positive
integers. Use a combinatorial proof to show that

$\binom{n_1}{2}$ + $\binom{n_2}{2}$ +...+ $\binom{n_k}{2}$ $\le$ $\binom{n_1 + n_2 + ...+ n_k}{2}$

For each $i$ with $1 ≤ i ≤ k$,
consider the complete graph on $n_i$ vertices. How many edges does this graph have?

Stuck on this problem and I don't know how to start. Was wondering if someone can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N=n_1+\cdots +n_k$. The expression on the right is the number of edges in the complete graph $K_N$.

The expression on the left is the number of edges in the $k$ disjoint subgraphs obtained by partitioning our $N$ vertices into sets of size $n_1,\ldots, n_k$, and examining the induced subgraph on each subset. Since the subgraphs are disjoint, no edge is counted twice, so we have our inequality.

Comment: How would one get the number of edges from the inequality though?

Comment: I don't understand. You don't get the number of edges from the inequality. You get the inequality because the left side counts a subset of the right side. We know that $\binom{n}{2}$ counts the number of edges in $K_n$; that's all we're using.